# Issues sending jpg-image over java socket using datainput/-outputstream

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, iostream, bufferedimage

I wish to send a JPG-image from a client to a server over a TCP socket connection. I convert the file to a byte array in the client then send it to the server after having sent the array length. The server reads the data one byte at a time from the socketinputstream to a new bytearray which is then written to a jpg-file. The data however is corrupted and this image cannot be viewed. Below is core java code for client and server.

Client:

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 666);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
String imgPath = "C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/prick1.JPG";
File file = new File(imgPath);
byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(b);
fis.close();
dos.writeInt((int) file.length());
dos.flush();
dos.write(b, 0, b.length);
dos.flush();
```

Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
Socket connect = serverSocket.accept();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
File file = new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/PLAYERprick.JPG");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
int arrlen = dis.readInt();
byte[] b = new byte[arrlen];
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < arrlen; i++) {
    b[i] = dis.readByte();
    i++;
}
fos.write(b, 0 , b.length);
```

I can't see why this wouldn't work and any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arrlen = dis.readInt();
byte[] b = new byte[arrlen];
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < arrlen; i++) {
    b[i] = dis.readByte();
    i++;
}
```

You're incrementing `i` twice so you're ignoring half the input, and writing what you don't ignore into the wrong slots. Fortunately there is an easier way, which is also much more efficient:

```
int arrlen = dis.readInt();
byte[] b = new byte[arrlen];
dis.readFully(b);
```

NB `fis.read(b);` isn't valid. You can't assume it fills the buffer. You should use `DataInputStream.readFully()` here too.

Comment: Heh, hadn't even noticed the double increment, easy to miss silly things when coding at 3am. The readFully() function worked magically too, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to match both ends of the socket and your client doesn't fill your `byte[]` fully; instead your client could send each byte as it reads it. And, since Java provides [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) you don't have to manually use and tweak a `byte[]` buffer directly. Instead you could do something like,

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 666);
String imgPath = "C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/prick1.JPG";
File file = new File(imgPath);
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());) {
    dos.writeLong(file.length()); // <-- remember to read a long on server.
    int val;
    while ((val = is.read()) != -1) {
        dos.write(val);
    }
    dos.flush();
}
```

Also, your server could use the similar [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) to get the benefit of a buffer like

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
File file = new File("C:/Users/huehuehue/Documents/Uni/D0036D/PLAYERprick.JPG");
try (Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
                s.getInputStream());
        OutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file));) {
    long arrlen = dis.readLong();
    for (long i = 0; i < arrlen; i++) {
        fos.write(dis.read());
    }
    fos.flush();
}
```

without having to manually manage it. Notice the above use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` to manage the buffering as an optimization. You could remove them and read and write directly from the `File` streams.

Comment: You haven't actually told him what's wrong with his code. Your code will write a whole lot of 0xff bytes if the sender terminates early. It needs to check for that.

Comment: @EJP It's 2014, it irks me when file protocols don't support > 2 GB files. Anyway, I included BufferedOutputStream in my original post but I've edited it to try and clarify.